# object goes out of scope before = operation

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have thous objects:

```
Polygon p1, p2;
```

And I have an inheriting class of `Polygon` called `Triangle`, and I try to do:

```
p1 = Triangle(temp1, temp2, temp3); // temp 1,2,3 are lengths of sides
```

But for some reason the destructor for `Triangle` is called at the end of construction.

```
Rectangle::~Rectangle(void)
{
    Polygon::~Polygon();
}

Polygon::~Polygon(void)
{
    if (sides != NULL)
    {
        delete [] sides;
        sides = NULL;
    }
}
```

Then it runs the destructor for `Polygon` a second time.

so after the code ends this is what the debugger says about `p1`( `n` is number of sides):

```
p1  {n=3 sides=0x0062c070 {-17891602} } Polygon
```

**Questions:**

- Why does it call the destructor?
- Why both `Triangle` and `Polygon`'s destructor are called?
- How can this be fixed?

EDIT:
as requested:

```
/*returns true if for the polygons A and B:
(a) for each side on polygon A there is an equal side on polygon B
(b) the number of sides in polygons A and B are equal
(c) sum of sides of A equals the sum of sides of B */
bool Polygon::operator==(const Polygon& p) const
{
    if (n != p.n)
        return false;
    if(circumference() != p.circumference())
        return false;
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
        if (!doesSideHasEqual(sides[i], p, n))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Also, thanks for the explanation why it ran `~Polygon`, will take into account.

Comment: `Destructor`, not deconstuctor. Show your `operator =`.

Comment: You don't need to call the `Polygon` dtor yourself. It will happen automatically after `Rectangle`s dtor.

Comment: You have [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) which means you need a good long read on C++ objects, pointers and references.

Comment: Also, a simple question : is your Polygon destructor virtual ?

Comment: no it is not virtual.

Comment: Your code is all kinds of bad. Please, [get a good book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks).

Comment: I am still a student, I am just learning basic Object Oriented, of-course my code is all kinds of bad.

Comment: testing for NULL before deleting is useless, `delete 0` is defined and well-behaved.

Comment: Manual memory management? Not knowing about slicing? Manually calling the base destructor? That means you didn't get started properly. Either your course is bad (like most are), or you picked the wrong book. Also, `operator==` != `operator=`.

Comment: It may be a bad course, I may be a bad student, who knows... about the second part... oh yea... operator= is not defined...I AM THE MOST STUPID MAN ON THE FACE OF THE EARTH...I shall go and cry in the corner now...that will solve the problem...I hope...

Comment: "will solve the problem" --- perhaps it will solve *a* problem (one of many).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Polygon p1;

p1 = Triangle(temp1, temp2, temp3); // temp 1,2,3 are lengths of sides
```

is in fact giving you result that is out of your expectation.

What you want to do is something like

```
Polygon& p1;
Triangle t(temp1, temp2, temp3);

p1 = t;
```

or

```
Polygon* p1 = new Triangle(temp1, temp2, temp3);
```

The problem in

```
p1 = Triangle(temp1, temp2, temp3);
```

is not only the Triangle object is temporary and destroyed right after the statement, but, more seriously, the copy from the Triangle object to p1 which is the Polygon, is only copying as is a Polygon.  Therefore, the "copied" p1 is not containing any information of Triangle.

---

Another problem is the way you write the destructor.  Destructor in C++ is automatically chained (I think you are coming from Java background which we need to explicitly invoke super class' finalizer)

```
Rectangle::~Rectangle(void)
{
    Polygon::~Polygon();  // can be removed
}
```

Therefore you shouldn't call Polygon's destructor.

Another thing about destructor is, if your class is supposed to be inherited (your Polygon is a good example), you should declare your destructor to be virtual.  For the reason behind, search for "virtual destructor".

Comment: Polygon is used as is in the same code, the destructor can not be virtual. also for the sake of this assignment, I should not yet use paramorphism, that is the next lesson.

Comment: well... I don't see the relationship between "destructor cannot be virtual" and "Polygon is used as is in the same code".  And, having virtual dtor in such case is almost the golden rule to follow, regardless what you are learning.  If that piece of code is given by your teacher, I am sorry about that.  (I am not apologising, I am feeling sorry that you have such teacher  :P )

Answer (score 2):

This line:

> ```
> p1 = Triangle(temp1, temp2, temp3);
> ```

Constructs a triangle object, then makes a *copy* of that object in p1, and the destroys the original object. It's the destructor for the original object you are seeing. (And it probably doesn't do what you want anyway because it will slice the object and only store the part of it that the base class has.)

Also you should not call the destructors for base classes in your destructors, they are called automatically.

And as a matter of style

```
if (sides != NULL)
{
    delete [] sides;
    sides = NULL;
}
```

There is no need to test sides before deleting it as delete on a null pointer does nothing by design. And there is little point setting sides to NULL as after the destructor is run the object doesnt exist anyway.

Comment: So how do you suggest I should put the new value in p1?

Comment: also the object slicing thingy is not a problem because Rectangle does not add new attributes or new functions, It is there just for the constructor (don't ask me why...that is just the exercise.)

Comment: @YitzhakGoldstine: My condolences that you have such a bad teacher.

Answer (score 0):

As you're still learning and somebody else answered your question, here's some pointers on C++ programming.

```
Polygon p1, p2;
```

That's two objects of class Polygon.

```
p1 = Triangle(temp1, temp2, temp3); // temp 1,2,3 are lengths of sides
```

This constructs an object of class `Triangle`, and calls an assignment-operator on `p1` to construct it from a `Triangle`. The `Triangle` is up-cast to a `Polygon` transparently and copy-constructed to `p1`, after which the `Triangle` temporary object is destroyed.

```
Rectangle::~Rectangle(void)
{
    Polygon::~Polygon();
}
```

This has one very major error and a subtle "old-style person" thing.

There is *never* a need to mention `(void)` in code; this was only sensible in C up to about 14 years ago. We're doing C++, and we're doing so in 2013, so don't use `(void)` but just use `()`. This already explicitly says no arguments are allowed.

The major problem though is that you're explicitly destructing the parent. The parent(s) are always implicitly destructed. This way they are first explicitly destructed, and then again implicitly destructed. Never call your destructor from your destructor.

```
Polygon::~Polygon(void)
{
    if (sides != NULL)
    {
        delete [] sides;
        sides = NULL;
    }
}
```

This reeks of "defensive programming". The code can be called multiple time and on half-constructed objects and it will not crash. On the other hand, you won't expose errors in other parts of your software either, so those will persist. A double-`delete` typically points to shared ownership and by extension a dangling pointer. This will mask that error perfectly.

Either decide that the `sides` member does have a value, or it does not. If it has a value, always delete it. For safety add an assert saying `sides != nullptr` or `sides != NULL` to check it beforehand, so that the code will crash with core file / stack trace if it doesn't.

If it may not have a value, *still* always delete it. Delete is safe for null pointer values, making for much cleaner code. This removes your check entirely. Setting it to `NULL` is allowed and will aid in finding use of a dangling pointer to this `Polygon` object.

Comment: A dangling pointer is a pointer to an object that's already destructed. `Polygon *a = new Polygon(); delete a;` . After this section, `a` is a dangling pointer to a destructed Polygon. Using it will not necessarily crash, but it will be very unreliable and should never be done.